# How to debug MATLAB script when calling it from Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.4

I'm calling a MATLAB script from python using

```
ml = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
output = ml.myMATLABscript(input1, input2)
```

The script runs fine in MATLAB, but when I call it from Python it runs into int vs double issues. So far I've been fixing this by interpreting the error message when the script crashes, but it would be nice to see what's going on specifically. For this purpose, I'd like to be able to step through the MATLAB code line for line, even though I've called it from Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is easier than I expected. Simply programatically set a breakpoint in the MATLAB script. For example:

```
dbstop if error
```

Then call the script from Python as before. The MATLAB editor will open in debug mode at the specified breakpoint.

This is also possible without editting the MATLAB script. In that case you need to set the MATLAB breakpoint from Python, using the enginge's eval:

```
ml = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
ml.eval(dbstop in myMATLABscript if error)
output = ml.myMATLABscript(input1, input2)
```

For completeness, from [MATLAB's documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html):

- `dbstop in file` sets a breakpoint at the first executable line in file.
- `dbstop in file at location` sets a breakpoint at the specified location
- `dbstop in file if expression` sets a conditional breakpoint at the first executable line of the file
- `dbstop in file at location if expression` sets a conditional breakpoint at the specified location.

Comment: Very nice, just out of curiosity: Does this need to go in the actual matlab script, or can you call it seperately from python (so you don't need to edit the script to debug).

Comment: Yes actually! I'll expand the answer to specify how.